# How to change the fonts of Title in Action bar in android

Tags: android, fonts, android-actionbar, material-design, android-toolbar

I want to change the Fonts of my title in the action bar. I have set the title programatically, in xml it was not showing any effect. Now I want to change the font of that title. I saw some post related to this, but It was not having the problem which I am facing.

Here is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //SETTING ITS LAYOUT
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.dancingscriptregular);


    //SETTING TITLE OF THE APP IN BLUE COULOR
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#1F9FD9'>Expense Manager <font>"));

  ...

 }
```

Now what next?, how to use the typeface to set the font of my title.

Please Help!

In androidMenifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity"
        android:name=".ExpenseActivity"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:label="@string/expenseActivity" <!--This Line is not working-->
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:textColor="@color/batteryChargedBlue"
        android:theme="@style/ExpenseTheme" />
    <activity
```

ExpenseTheme

```
<style name="ExpenseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/batteryChargedBlue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/greenBlue</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/batteryChargedBlue</item>

</style>
```

activity_start.xml Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".StartActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/part_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/part_2"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/greenBlue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/caviar_dreams_bold"
        android:text="Welcome !!!"
        android:textSize="55dp"


        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/greenBlue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/dancingscriptregular"
        android:text="@string/info"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/imaEt"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/enterIMA"
        android:background="@drawable/border_and_lines_tp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/greenBlue"
        android:fontFamily="@font/caviar_dreams_bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/imaBtn"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@color/batteryChargedBlue"
        android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"
        android:text="Enter"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="setInitialMonthlyAmount"
        app:cornerRadius="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/imaSkip"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/batteryChargedBlue"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="setOnSkipClicked"
        app:cornerRadius="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <!-- <Button
         android:id="@+id/imaBtn"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
         android:background="@drawable/borders_and_lines"
         android:onClick="setInitialMonthlyAmount"
         android:text="Enter"
         android:textColor="#FFF" /> -->

    <!-- <Button
         android:id="@+id/imaSkip"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
         android:text="Continue >>"
         android:textColor="#FFF"
         android:onClick="setOnSkipClicked"
         android:background="@drawable/borders_and_lines"
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="30dp"
         /> -->



</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/part_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/help"
        android:textColor="@color/greenBlue"
        android:fontFamily="@font/dancingscriptregular"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[This my actual layout and I have achieved by using the following file, which I have posted. now I just want to change the font of the black circled text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQeeD.jpg)

Comment: share your xml,it will be better to set font and color on xml itself.

Comment: here, I have added @EmadSeliem

Comment: please share your toolbar xml file.

Comment: I don't have any such file!! @EmadSeliem

Comment: Check Out my Edit and Image @EmadSeliem

Comment: This Question has been Answered! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046647/how-to-change-the-fonts-of-title-in-action-bar-in-android/58046798#58046798 Check this Link ↑

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use these code:

if you are using "Holo Theme" then use this:

```
    int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id",
            "android");
    TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
    yourTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
   Typeface yourTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your_font.ttf");
   //or get from resource
   yourTextView.setTypeface(yourTypeface);
```

if you are using "Material Theme" then use this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
TextView textView1 = (TextView) toolbar.getChildAt(0);//title
TextView textView2 = (TextView) toolbar.getChildAt(1);//subtitle
textView1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
textView2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
   Typeface yourTypeface1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your_font1.ttf");
   Typeface yourTypeface2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your_font2.ttf");
   //or get from resource
   textView1.setTypeface(yourTypeface1);
   textView2.setTypeface(yourTypeface2);
```

it works and it is very simple!
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199826/discussion-on-answer-by-majid-ghafouri-how-to-change-the-fonts-of-title-in-actio).

Comment: R.id.action_bar - ID of Toolbar perfect, but what is the ID of Title and SubTitle..?

Comment: You can access them with getChildAt() method. @V.Y.

Answer (score 8):

You have different options.
In your activity you can use something like in your layout:

```
   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            style="@style/MyToolbar"
            ...
            />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Then you can define a custom style:

```
  <!-- Toolbar -->
  <style name="MyToolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/My_TextAppearance_Toolbar</item>    
  </style>

  <style name="My_TextAppearance_Toolbar" parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6">
    <item name="fontFamily">....</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">....</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Otherwise you can also use **the `Toolbar` API**:

```
   toolbar.setTitle("Material Title");
   toolbar.setTitleTextAppearance(this,R.style.My_TextAppearance_Toolbar);
```

**Another option** is to use **`app:titleTextAppearance`** attribute in your layout:

```
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/My_TextAppearance_Toolbar"
            .../>
```

Comment: I don't want to create any toolbar. I have default actionbar in my activity. whose title I have set using getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#1F9FD9'>Expense Manager <font>"));. Now I just Want to change the font. Is there any simpler way. Can you study my code and then tell me where to put your codes.@GabrieleMariotti

Comment: Check Out my Edit and Image @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: @Nomankhanbhai It is not a problem. Just use `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`. In this way you can continue using the ActionBar API. Otherwise you can use the Toolbar API and use `toolbar.setTitle(...)`. I've just updated the answer with other options. You can use the Toolbar API or the ActionBar API as you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a custom toolbar.
Stay with me...

`in xml layout(activity_start.xml), you add code below to xml file:`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activity.YourActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" (**id of toolbar**)
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" (**color of background**)
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"> (**direction-rtl-ltr**)

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Start Activity" (**text for display on toolbar**)
                android:textSize="23dp" (**text size**)
                android:fontFamily="@font/yekan" (**font of text :D**)
                android:textColor="#ffffff" (**text color**)
                (**And any other code you like for textview :)*)
            />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

This way you can have an actionbar with a font without writing code in the Java file.

Add code below to java file:
And to use the toolbar in Java code you can get it with code below:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

EDIT: **If you encounter an error while using `AppBarLayout`, Create `BasicActivity` Then follow the steps above**

Comment: I cleared my previous code, then I copied your code in the xml and removed the hits and texts. After that there were no errors but in the preview section. it was just showing this (<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout...) text in grey background. My android studio is using androidx libraries FYI. May because of that. Do you have any other way to do it. @Reza

Comment: @Noman khanbhai I didn't say erase the previous codes. I said add my code to the xml layer.
I edited my answer. check it...

Comment: I am editing my post and sharing my xml code. Kindly show me where to put your code and also check my androidMenifest and .StartActivity Theme(It is using ExpenseTheme)[Which already contains ActionBar]. @Reza

Comment: Here, I have Provided my activity_start.xml code. @Reza

Comment: Change the colorPrimary in the theme for display the title.

Comment: Check Out my Edit and Image @Reza

Comment: Really Thank you for your kind Help and Support @Reza  . Solution of majidghafouri worked for me. Can you please upvote my post.

Comment: I edited the answer. Check out... @Noman khanbhai